# Qt: How to avoid Windows soft keyboard covering input field?

Tags: windows, qt, qml, tablet, soft-keyboard

On the iPad, if a QML `TextInput` or `TextEdit` gains focus, the soft keyboard appears and the app content slides up as necessary so that both the text input field and the soft keyboard are visible.

On a Windows Surface Tablet, in tablet mode, Qt supports automatic showing of the soft keyboard, but the app content does not automatically slide up and the input field can be hidden behind the keyboard.

Is there a way to make the app content slide up automatically as it does on the iPad? Or is there a way to detect the **presence** and **dimensions** of the soft keyboard so that I can handle the slide up manually in code?

NB: the automatic showing of the soft keyboard on Windows in tablet mode was [reported broken in this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43190) (reported as early as Qt 5.3.2) but [has been fixed as of Qt 5.11.2](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68808). Note also: these bugs affected Qt Widgets class `QLineEdit` also, and my issue may relate to that too but I have not tested it with Widgets.